# Mac doesn't run binary from terminal

Tags: macos

I have a `rlwrap` installed in:

> /usr/local/bin

that does not run because it is from an unidentified developer. I did make it to work by adding it to the exceptions (by control-click and open), but it only works if I run it from Finder.

When I try open it from terminal it doesn't run. Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks.

Things I tried and didn't work:

1. `sudo rlwrap`
2. <kbd>control</kbd>-click and open
3. `sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine rlwrap`
4. System Preferences -> Security and Privacy and enabled applications from "Anywhere"

I can execute `rlwrap` from Finder, but just not from terminal.

- I'm running on Mavericks

Comment: Can you explain exactly what happens when you try to run it? Can you copy/paste the terminal output? Does it exit zero or nonzero (that is, if you run `echo $?` right after running it, do you get a zero or another number)? Does anything (what exactly?) get logged to the system logs?

Comment: Also: Do you have `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH`? What does `ls -leO@ /usr/local/bin/rlwrap` report? What does `file /usr/local/bin/rlwrap` report?

Comment: @Spiff when I run `echo $?` right after it I get 126. `/usr/local/bin` should be in my `$PATH` because I can run other programs in it. `ls -leO@ /usr/local/bin/rlwrap` reports `-rwx------@ 1 liuhong  staff  - 214009 Jan 23 09:43 /usr/local/bin/rlwrap
 com.apple.ResourceFork   1338 `. `file ...` reports `/usr/local/bin/rlwrap: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, based on your latest comments, it looks like you're trying to run a Linux ELF binary on OS X. OS X doesn't have a Linux ABI compatibility layer built in. You need to compile (or download) and install an OS X x86_64 Mach-o binary of rlwrap.

I'm not sure why you thought you were able to execute rlwrap from the Finder, since I don't see any way this could actually have executed.

Comment: oh ya my apologies sir